# Stored Procedure in PHP MySQLi returns error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a stored procedure that I use to pull a result set from a database. Depending on the parameter, it may return 0 records (this is normal). My only problem is that in the instance where it returns 0 records, PHP throws an exception. Here is my code;

```
public function MyMethod($strParam)
    {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $strSQL = "spStoredProc(?)";
        $objStatement = $this->objDB->prepare($strSQL);

        $objStatement->bind_param("s",$strParam);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $objResult = $objStatement->get_result();
        if (!$objResult) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->objDB->errno}] {$this->objDB->error}");  //<<thrown
        }
        $objReturn = array();
        while($objRow = $objResult->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $objReturn[] = $objRow;
        }
        return $objReturn;
    }
```

The exception thrown is;

```
 Uncaught Exception: Database Error [0]  in /var/www/bla/dbClass.php:56\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/bla/main.php(19): dbClass->MyMethod('stuff')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/bla/dbClass.php on line 56
```

Stored Procedure create code

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `spStoredProc`(IN `strParam` VARCHAR(50))
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
//bunch of code
END
```

So when I run;

```
var_dump($myDBObj->MyMethod("ShouldReturnZeroRows")) //exception
var_dump($myDBObj->MyMethod("ShouldReturnTenRows")) //works great!
```

Is there something that I have misunderstood about stored procedures where they would cause prepared statements to fail with no results returned?

Server is Ubuntu running PHP Version 7.0.8, MySQL 5.7.16.

Comment: The thrown error code is `[0]` so everthing is ok, but you are throwning that error because `$objResult` is `false` and that is maybe the result of the query (no rows found). so check the result in another way too throw an error only a real error turns up. `$this->objDB->errno > 0`

Comment: Ok, that's odd, because when I use a standard query with no results,  $objResult is true... I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but check also the mysql error log, it is still an `stored procedure` and im not really into it. :) But in the end error code `0` seems fine.

Comment: @JOUM if you want to add this as a solution, I will mark it as the answer. It worked great. Thanks again.